# Maximal-score path of length K in a M x N matrix

Tags: java, algorithm

While working on a different problem, I came across this one:

> Given a matrix and an integer *k*, find the path of length *k* within the matrix that maximizes the sum of the cells in the path. The path can start at any cell, can proceed in any direction, and can turn freely at each point. The path can also intersect itself, but if it does, a given cell only counts *once* toward the sum.
>
> Return the sum.

In order to solve this problem I tried a recursive approach, in which for every possible starting position (i.e. all the elements of the matrix) I compute the longest path possible and try to use a lookup table so that repeating a certain point in the grid yield a value of 0. The problem is that I'm not sure how and when to re-initialize the lookup table so that I don't lose possible routes.

My implementation so far looks something like this.

```
    int maxP(int i, int j, int steps, int[][] grid) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= n || j < 0 || j >= m || steps < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        // check if place has been passed through before
        int cost;
        if (lookup[i][j] == 1) {
           cost = 0;
        } else {
           cost = grid[i][j];
           lookup[i][j] = 1;
       }

       return cost + max(
            maxP(i - 1, j - 1, steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i - 1, j, steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i - 1, j + 1,steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i, j - 1,  steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i, j + 1, steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i + 1, j - 1, steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i + 1, j, steps - 1, grid),
            maxP(i + 1, j + 1, steps - 1, grid)
       );
}
```

Comment: With the way you are doing it, you would need to take the `grid` and then split into 8 different grids every time you recurse. This will get space intensive rather quickly, which may mean you have to move to a more heuristic way of going about this problem (unless `m` and `n` are small)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think that grid could be initialized in a way such that its more of a maze rather than just a rectangle. Maybe there is some code that reflects this that he didn't show? Idk, just some thoughts.

Comment: Sigh, I missed the letter `K` in the title. There's no mention of `K` in the body of the question, and I overlooked the variable `steps` in the code. So to answer @NicoSchertler, the challenge is to get the best score without taking more than `K` steps.

Comment: And the answer to *"how and when to re-initialize the lookup table"* is that `lookup[i][j]` needs to be a count of how many times a grid position is visited. When entering a grid position, increment the count. When backtracking, decrement the count. Which is to say that you never *"re-initialize the lookup table"*. You always maintain the table incrementally.

Comment: @user3386109 I  think your suggestion will indeed lead to the desired outcome. I have to admit though that I am not sure how I should properly implement it in the context of my code. Could you please give a few more pointers?

Comment: @IPopescu I moved the comment into an answer, and added code to show how to implement the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to *"how and when to re-initialize the lookup table"* is that `lookup[i][j]` needs to be a count of how many times a grid position is visited. When entering a grid position, increment the count. When backtracking, decrement the count. Which is to say that you never *"re-initialize the lookup table"*. You always maintain the table incrementally.

Here's what the modified code looks like:

```
int maxP(int i, int j, int steps, int[][] grid) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= n || j < 0 || j >= m || steps < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // check if place has been passed through before
    int cost = 0;
    if (lookup[i][j] == 0) {
        cost = grid[i][j];
    }

    // mark this place as visited
    lookup[i][j]++;

    // find the best cost recursively
    cost = cost + max(
                      maxP(i - 1, j - 1, steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i - 1, j, steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i - 1, j + 1,steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i, j - 1,  steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i, j + 1, steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i + 1, j - 1, steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i + 1, j, steps - 1, grid),
                      maxP(i + 1, j + 1, steps - 1, grid)
                      );

    // undo the change to the lookup table
    lookup[i][j]--;

    return cost;
}
```